# if and else inside function of class

Tags: php, function, class

This code:

full code: http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/textable/textable/textable.class.php

```
function read_table($b=''){
    $lines = file($this->filename);

    if ($b == 1) {
        $linesa = arsort($lines);
    }


    foreach ( $lines as $row ){
        if (strlen($row) > 1){
            $temp = explode("~", $row);
            $temp[count($temp) - 1] = rtrim($temp[count($temp) - 1]);
            $this->table[] = $temp;
        }
    }
}
```

I try to call class like this:

```
$DBnews->table(1);
```

but it's not working

Comment: "*It is not working*" is not useful. Please explain, if you get an error message (if so, which one) or if the results differ from your expectation (if so, how).

Comment: ...also I don't see any method called `table` defined anywhere. What do you try to achive? If you want to call `read_table` method, you need to call it by it's name / so something like `$DBnews->read_table(1);`

Comment: `table` != `read_table` >>>> `$DBnews->table(1);` != `function read_table($b=''){`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `table` property is an array. I think you might have meant

```
$DBnews->table[1];
```

to access 2nd element in array.